# Fetch Request Error

Tags: swift, core-data, fetch, nsfetchrequest

I've saved a user input name in the previous storyboard into the xcdatamodel under the entity "UserInfo" with the name "name". I'm trying to fetch it in the next storyboard to display in a label to greet the user. I'm getting the error "Cannot Invoke Initializer for type 'NSFetchRequet' with an Argument with list of type '(entityName:String, attributeName: String)"

```
     guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
     return
     }

     //getting the managed context where the entity we need is
     let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

     //make fetch request
     let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "UserInfo", attributeName: "name")


     //try to fetch the entity we need, else print error
     do {
     Username = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
     } catch let error as NSError {
     print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no initializer for `NSFetchRequest` that takes the argument `attributeName:`, just like the error says. Your options are `NSFetchRequest(entityName:)` or `NSFetchRequest()`.

When in doubt, look up the class in the API reference to make sure you understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFetchRequest` doesn't have an initializer `entityName:attributeName`, you have to use

```
 let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "UserInfo")
```

`fetch` returns always an array. If there is only one record in the entity, get the first item and the value for attribute `name`:

```
 do {
     let users = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
     if let user = users.first {
         Username = user.value(forKey: "name")
     }
 } catch let error as NSError {
     print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
 }
```

If there are multiple records you might apply a predicate.

---

And don't `guard` `AppDelegate`. If this class didn't exist the app won't even launch. The exclamation mark is *safe as safe can*.

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```